# Creating common method for two classes not using inheritance in java

Tags: java, class, methods

I'm just wondering if there is any way to create two classes that aren't related but have the same implementation of method. I know there are interfaces and static methods but it seems like they are good only when you have static field in class. Is this possible to do that kind of thing when method uses field that is specific to exact object? 
I know it's a bad practice writing code like this but I'm just curious.

EDIT:
I mean something like this:

```
public class Person implements MakingOlder {
  private int age;
}

public class Cat implements MakingOlder {
  private int age;
}

public interface MakingOlder {
  public static void makeOlder() {
        this.age += 2;
  }
}
```

I don't want to make common base class for Person and Cat and interface is not working. I'm trying to avoid writing the same implementation twice and copying the code.

Comment: You want to write the same method twice?  Perhaps you could illustrate this question with an example of what you're trying to achieve and why?

Comment: Probably Generics will help you. but you need to provide more info about your classes

Comment: Write a static method that takes the object you want to work on as its input. An example of this is the static `Object.hash(Object)`.

Comment: Can you add some code to clarify?  Given class `Z` which implements some method, classes `A`, and `B` could delegate to `Z` to avoid code duplication.

Comment: Re: your edit... This is a classic academic use case for an abstract base class.  Why don't you want to use that?

Comment: I think generics also wouldn't be helpful. I can't using inheritance because both of my classes have base classes and it's not possible to make something like intermediate-base class... Multiple inheritance can solve my problem but I can't do this in java.

Comment: My code doesn't look like this, I just wrote an example to clarify a bit what I'm talking about.

Comment: @im_a_cat: *"it's not possible to make something like intermediate-base class"* - It's possible to have an inheritance hierarchy more than two classes deep.  That's part of the academic exercise here.  Continuing with the example of biological entities as classes, if you go back far enough everything has common base ancestry.

Comment: I mean, in my example I can't create intermediate-base class (I didn't say it is generally impossible, I knew it's possible) and it's not academic exercise but thanks for trying to help me

Comment: The cleanest way to do this is called a *mixin*, and while it's supported by Groovy, it's not supported by Java or Kotlin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, it's called "composition + delegation", and it's often a good practice to replace inheritance by this :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

```
public class Person implements AgingObject {
  private int age;  
  private AgingBehavior agingBehavior;

  void makeOlder() {
    agingBehavior.makeOlder(this);
  }
  //(...)
}

public class Cat implements AgingObject {
  private int age;
  private AgingBehavior agingBehavior;

  void makeOlder() {
    agingBehavior.makeOlder(this);
  }
  //(...)
}

public class AgingBehavior {
  void makeOlder(AgingObject agingObject) {
    agingObject.setAge(agingObject.getAge() + 2);
  }
}

public interface AgingObject {
    int getAge();
    void setAge(int age);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

...or you can use default implementation in Java 8+...

```
public interface MakingOlder {

    public default void makeOlder() {
        setAge(getAge() + 2);
    }

    int getAge();

    void setAge(int age);

}
```

and of course your Person and Cat implements `MakingOlder`...

Answer (score 0):

Probably your interface is not working because you are trying to implement a method within the interface:

```
public static void makeOlder() {
    this.age += 2;
}
```

In order to make it work, try to add the `default` keyword so that it looks like:

```
default Integer makeOlder(Integer age) {
    age += 2;
    return age;
}
```

Then the class, which implements that interface, will just need to contain something like:

```
public class Dummy implements AA {

    Integer age;

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

To test the result you can call something like:

```
Dummy d = new Dummy();
d.setAge(d.makeOlder(7));
System.out.println(d.getAge());
d.setAge(d.makeOlder(d.getAge()));
System.out.println(d.getAge());
```

Comment: ...just my opinion, it's not very nice, that caller of `makeOlder`, have to call setter for age...